imakeidx - Hyphen between two consecutive pages, again
I'm trying to make an index with the package imakeidx and I have the same problem as here : imakeidx: How can I hyphenate entries of two consecutive pages?. There isn't any response so I ask it again.
I want to replace the comma by a hyphen when the word I'm indexing is on two consecutive pages, i.e. replace

Word 1, 4, 5, 7

by

Word 1, 4-5, 7

Thank you in advance !

It is indeed the same question and the answer is still the same as in @egreg's comment.

@cabohah: Well, AFAICS egreg only explained "why not". Thank you for also showing a useful "how to"; that was missing there.

imakeidx only prepares input for MakeIndex and does the run of that program automatically to allow preparation of an index (at the end of the document) in a single run. MakeIndex does provide automatically range formatting only for three or more consecutive pages. So the only suggestion for two pages would be to do it manually using the range operator:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually}
\Blindtext[16]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually|(} % using range start
\Blindtext[4]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually|)} % using range end
\Blindtext[16]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually}
\Blindtext[16]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually}
\Blindtext[5]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually}
\Blindtext[5]

Automatically\index{Automatically} or manually\index{Manually}
\Blindtext[5]

\printindex
\end{document}



I thought there might be a way of lowering the range limit to 2 instead of 3 but I'm going to do it manually in that case. Thanks anyway !!
